# Blender command line open template

Tags: scripting, command-line

Hi and thanks for reading.
I'm newbie and have problem to solve with Blender.
We have a upper level app which will open a template of Blender with a button in GUI (for make difference startup file and userpref file).
But I can't found in docs that argument for open template file so I'm asking community for help if this option is possible, if not hope anyone can help me Python script option for this problem.
Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by template? Is it just a blend file you want to open?

Comment: I'm just copy from docs: "Application templates are a feature that allows you to define a re-usable configuration that can be selected to replace the default configuration, without requiring a separate Blender installation or overwriting your personal settings."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no CLI option to choose which [application templates](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/app_templates.html) is open at startup, you need to use python to tell blender to open one of the templates.

You need to call the [`bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile) operator, using `--python-expr` in the [CLI arguments](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) should be enough -

```
blender --python-expr "import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile(app_template='usertemplate')"
```